# C# MySQLBulkLoader overwriting timestamp

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working with some massive datasets and I am using the MySQLBulkLoader to import the data into my database. However I am having issues with the MySQLBulkLoader overwriting my timestamp column which is auto-updated. To contextualize assume I have the following structure:

```
Timestamp  | Name | Age | Height
--------------------------------
2011-01-01 | Jeff | 30  | 183
2012-02-03 | Bob  | 55  | 165
2016-04-05 | Sue  | 33  | 155.
```

The data file I am loading in with the MySQLBulkLoader is a CSV which only contains the last three columns as shown below:

```
Name,Age,Height
Jeff,30,183
Bob,55,165
Sue,33,155
```

The issues I am having is that the first column in the CSV writes into the first column of the database. So I need to be able to:

- **Ignore** the **first column** or bulk insert, or
- **Bulk insert** into a **subset** of columns

Thanks, your assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to provide the answer to the question. The My SQL function:

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name'
    [REPLACE | IGNORE]
    INTO TABLE tbl_name
    [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
        [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
        [ESCAPED BY 'char']
    ]
    [LINES
        [STARTING BY 'string']
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    ]
    [IGNORE number LINES]
    [(col_name_or_user_var,...)]
    [SET col_name = expr,...]
```

Allows for the loading of the data into specific columns by specifying the column names. I struggled to get this operation working by manually creating the query but was able to modify the MySQLBulkLoader function. By default that function does not allow for the setting of the columns as the columns list is read only. But I modified the function to allow for the setting of column names. Once the modification was made the system write the data into the correct columns and the timestamp was maintained.